# Android Room Entity inheritance

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-database

I've already seen a threads similar to this, but none of them answers my question.

---

So let's say we have **two classes**:

- Lesson
- Break

Both of them are implementing **SchoolEntity** interface, which has the following methods:

1. Date getStartDate()
2. Date getEndDate()

**Break** class does nothing beside implementing this interface, but **Lesson** has additional fields and getters, like:

1. subject
2. room
3. teacher, etc.

Now I want to save **instance** of **SchoolEntity** using  Android's **Room Persistence Library**.

---

This is the **List** I want to be saved:

```
List<SchoolEntity> timetable:
 1. Lesson@13da43:
    - Date startDate = Date@ha94j8
    - Date endDate = Date@9kf8kf
    - String subject = "math"
    - String room = "124"
    - String teacher = "Joseph Fold"
 2. Break@j7gfsd:
    - Date startDate = Date@738291
    - Date endDate = Date@fj8fjn
```

And I want **it** to be saved in **SQL Database** like this:

```
+----------------------+---------------------+--------+---------+------+-------------+
| start_date           | end_date            | type   | subject | room | teacher     |
+----------------------+---------------------+--------+---------+------+-------------+
| 2019.01.12 08:00:00  | 2019.01.12 08:45:00 | LESSON | math    | 124  | Joseph Fold |
| 2019.01.12 08:45:00  | 2019.01.12 08:55:00 | BREAK  | NULL    | NULL | NULL        |
+----------------------+---------------------+--------+---------+------+-------------+
```

> Note: **start_date** is primary key

And finally I want to be able to retrive saved information as:

```
LiveData<List<SchoolEntity>> timetable
```

---

My **question** is:

**Am I able to do this using Android's Room Persistence Library? If so, how to achieve it? If no what should I use instead?**

---

My language is Java, but Kotlin will also make me.

Comment: `start_date` as primary key is doomed to fail... so what if you have more than 1 class, starting at 8:00 am?

Comment: It's no how school lessons work. One lesson have to end to another be started.

Comment: a school commonly has more than 1 single class starting at 8:00 am ...most likely in different rooms. while actually, anything that is not a lesson is a break; therefore it's also pointless to store the breaks. using a timestamp as primary key prevents more than 1 single class starting at 8:00 am in different rooms. you'd rather need classes `Lesson`, `Teacher`, `Subject`, `Room` (which may collide with the `Room` namespace). it might also be of interest, who even attends these classes.

Comment: You get me wrong. It's not a school menagment system, but timetable menager app for students. Each student has his own timetable, where lessons can't collide with each other. Also having seperate classes for each lesson information is pointless, as it will be used only to be displayed on a screen

Comment: If you are open to trying out a different ORM, check out JDXA ORM for Android. JDXA supports inheritance where the objects of the class hierarchy may be stored either in one table  cumulatively (as shown in your question) or in different tables for different classes. Disclaimer: I am the architect for JDXA.

Comment: Yeah, I will try it for sure

Comment: @PawełKiełb, Great. Please let me know if you have any questions about JDXA.